# Get hash that has min value in array of objects

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes that look like this:

```
objects = [ {:area => -30}, {:area => 20}, {:area => 30}]
```

How would I get the hash which area is lower, **but that is always bigger than 0**?

I have tried this:

```
objects.min_by { |el| (el[:area] if el[:area] > 0) }
```

But I guess that since (if...) returns NIL, it can't compare with the other values.  How can I do that?

Comment: Hommer, you might want to consider reorganizing your code so you are not faced with this question.  For example, perhaps you could obtain `{:area => [-30, 20, 30]}` earlier in the calculation, so you don't have the repetition of the identical keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objects = [ {:area => -30}, {:area => 20}, {:area => 30}]
objects.select{|h| h[:area] > 0}.min_by{|h| h[:area] }
# => {:area=>20}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this:

```
objects.reject{|x| x[:area] <= 0}.min_by{|x| x[:area]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) that is providing you a sort of "map & reduce" feature.

```
objects = [ {:area => -30}, {:area => 20}, {:area => 30}]
objects.inject(nil) { |result, item| item[:area] > 0 && (result.nil? || item[:area] < result) ? item[:area] : result }
# => 20
```

You can simplify it by setting a value instead of nil as the first value (or a big value) and skipping the nil.

```
objects = [ {:area => -30}, {:area => 20}, {:area => 30}]
objects.inject(objects[0][:area]) { |result, item| item[:area] > 0 && item[:area] < result ? item[:area] : result }
# => 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use inject:

```
objects.inject(nil) do |result, item|
  if item[:area] > 0 && (result.nil? || item[:area] < result[:area])
    item
  else
    result
  end
end
```